# Asus Zenbook: how do I apply the bluetooth patch for 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, kernel, bash

> **Note: There is no need for a patch if you are running Ubuntu 12.04**

I am following  [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbook#How_to_recompile_kernel_for_Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_and_ux31e) instructions to recompile a kernel with working bluetooth for my Asus Zenbook UX31E. However, when typing `patch -p1 linux-3.3-rc5 ./bluetooth.patch` (where **linux-3.3-rc5** is the folder I unzipped the kernel) as suggested in the 4th step, I get only an error saying:

```
patch: **** File linux-3.3-rc5 is not a regular file -- can't patch
```

Am I doing something wrong? I would really want to get bluetooth working on my laptop, otherwise Ubuntu runs flawlessly on it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace Step 4 in the [howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbook#How_to_recompile_kernel_for_Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_and_ux31e) with the below:

1. `cd` into the uncompressed kernel directory, e.g. `cd linux-3.3-rc5`
2. Then paste the following to download and directly apply the patch:

   ```
   wget -q -O- http://fenski.pl/zenbook/bluetooth.patch | \ 
   sed -e 's#linux-3.2.5/##g' -e 's#linux-3.2.5.orig/##g' | patch -p0
   ```
3. Continue with the howto and compile the kernel!